# Building a dynamic formwith React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

G'day.  I am trying to construct a dynamic form using react, redux, redux-for and my own routines.  I cycle through the description in JSON of the form, then build JSX in my parser.

When I finally get back to the calling component it just renders as one big string!

```
<Accordion uniqId={'addAsset'} {...this.props} singleOpen={true} > <AccordionSection title=Asset Summary - Mandatories noFunctions=12 noFunctionsDone=0 validated={true} required={true} openByDefault={true} > <p>RenderInput</p><p>RenderInput</p></AccordionSection> <AccordionSection title=Asset Summary - Mandatories noFunctions=12 noFunctionsDone=0 validated={true} required={true} openByDefault={true} > </AccordionSection></Accordion>
```

The calling component does this

> render() { const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
>
> return (
>
> #### Add Asset
>
> ```
>     <div className="col-sm-12">
>         <form  className="form-horizontal" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
>             <div className="well">
>                 <SmartForm form={assetForm}   />
>             </div>
>             <div>
>                 <button type="submit" id="createSave" className="btn btn-info btn-space next">Create & Save</button>
>                 <button type="submit" className="btn btn-info btn-space next">Save & Close</button>
>                 <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success btn-space next">Save & Publish</button>
>                 <button type="submit" className="btn btn-danger btn-space next">Close</button>
>                 <button type="submit" className="btn btn-space next">More</button>
>             </div>
>         </form>
>     </div>
> </div>
>     );
> ```

SmartForm does this

```
   //--------
    render() {
        return(
                <div>
                    <h2>SmartForm Parser</h2>
                    {this.parse(this.props.form)}
                </div>
        );
```

and parse is a helper that returns an array (of what I thought were lines of code that could be rendered).

I am getting something quite wrong.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to render raw HTML in JSX.

```
createMarkup() {
  return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'};
}
render() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

The important part being that you have to return it in an object with a `__html` key.